# PHP DateTime function returns dates in future for this week

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to find the date range for "this week" using the following PHP code:

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $dateFrom = new DateTime('Monday this week');
    $dateTo = new DateTime('Sunday this week');

    $periodTextFrom = $dateFrom->format('Y/m/d 00:00:00');
    $periodTextTo = $dateTo->format('Y/m/d 23:59:59');

    echo $periodTextFrom.'<br>';
    echo $periodTextTo.'<br>';

?>
```

If I run today (Sunday 19th July 2015) it gives me the following output:

```
2015/07/20 00:00:00
2015/07/26 23:59:59
```

that is all in the future and not "this" week at all.

Why is this and how can I correct?

Comment: Sunday is the start of the week, so your end date is your start, and your start is the next day. To be more precise, if today is Sunday, "Monday this week" is tomorrow.

Comment: So surely that would give $dateFrom as 2015/07/20 and $dateTo as 2015/07/19?

Comment: Not if *Sunday is defined as the start of a week.*

Comment: Try "Monday last week" and "Sunday" I think that'll get what you want...at least on Sundays...

Comment: I still don't get why, if Sunday is the start of the week, PHP doesn't return 2015/07/19 as it was run on a Sunday and, by definition, it was "this week".

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
 $today = getdate();

 $weekStart = $today['mday'] - $today['wday'];
 $weekEnd = $today['mday'] - $today['wday']+6;

 echo "week start:".$today['year']."/".$today['mon'].'/'.$weekStart."\nweek end:".$today['year']."/".$today['mon'].'/'.$weekEnd;
```

Comment: This does indeed work and gives me what I want. Still not convinced that PHP isn't wrong with my previous example though! Thanks

Comment: On reflection I don't think it does work. If, say, it is run on 1st of the month and it is a Friday as I think it gives (1 - 6) = -5.